# Apache - mod_rewrite file extension rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For rewriting extensions, I found the following set of rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

But these rules fail for a non-existing file/directory as they keep adding `.php` after every redirect ending in an infinite loop.

Can something changed in the existing rules to fix that or do I need to remove the `L` flag and add, after that, another condition and rule to check if the `*.php` file exists?

> **I am using apache 2.2 so `END` flag is not applicable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can something changed in the existing rules to fix that or do I need to remove the L flag and add, after that, another condition and rule to check if the *.php file exists?

Don't remove `L` flag and as you said you should add condition to check if a not-existing file is `.php` or not but not after rule ,before applying it, like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)  $1.php [L]
```